# override gitignore in subfolder

Tags: git, gitignore

Consider the following file structure:

- RootFolder

  - .gitignore
  - SubFolder

    - dist
    - .gitignore (it ignores the dist folder)

The .gitignore in the SubFolder is ignoring the dist folder. Is there any way I can include the dist folder by editing the .gitignore in the RootFolder?

I have like 20 SubFolders with the same .gitignore, it would be wonderful if I am able to do this, instead of going into each SubFolder and edit the gitignore manually to include the dist folders.

Comment: Just wondering: Are there actually any `dist` folders that you really want to ignore that justifies such a rule in the root `.gitignore`? I would usually suggest to try to only have a single `.gitignore` for the whole project. That really helps maintaining it.

Comment: These files are generated as the result of a conversion from an older repo, I need to fix this later, to have only one in the root as you say

Comment: Could you still answer my question?

Comment: Each subfolder has a separate dist folder, which is ignored by the gitignore in that subfolder. I need to include the dist folders, as I need to have them for my CI process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `.gitignore` in the `SubFolder` is ignoring the `dist` folder. Is there any way I can include the `dist` folder by editing the `.gitignore` in the `RootFolder`?

I misunderstoot that part first and thought it was the exact opposite. To answer this question: No, this won’t be possible.

Gitignore files in subdirectories will always have a higher precedence over those in a parent directory. This is done to allow having generic rules in the root that can be overridden with more specific rules in a subdirectory.

---

What you could do however is to simply get rid of all those `.gitignore` files in the subdirectories. Since you mentioned that they are all the same anyway, you could just remove them completely and put the still-relevant rules in the root’s `.gitignore`.